# Ionic serve show this error Ionic2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

in this typescript code i define `public currentLocation : {lat: number, lng: number};` and i get value of `currentLocation` inside  `this.geolocation` method in `console.log(this.currentLocation)`. but outside of this block in `console.log(this.currentLocation)`  i got undefine. How can i get value in global variable?

```
export class DetailsPage {

  typeDetails: {};

  public currentLocation : {lat: number, lng: number};

   posOptions = {
  enableHighAccuracy: true,
  timeout: 20000,
  maximumAge: 0
};



  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
          public navParams: NavParams,
          private typeApi : TypeApi,
          public geolocation : Geolocation) {}


  ionViewDidLoad() {
  let baseUrl  ='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.2150756,72.8880545&radius=500&type=hospital&key=AIzaSyBldIefF25dfjjtMZq1hjUxrj4T4hK66Mg';
    this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

      this.currentLocation ={
          lat :resp.coords.latitude,
          lng :resp.coords.longitude

      };

 console.log(this.currentLocation);


    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });


  console.log(this.currentLocation);



console.log('ionViewDidLoad DetailsPage');

     //this.typeDetails = this.typeApi.getTypeDetails();
     //console.log(this.typeDetails);

    this.typeApi.getTypeDetails().then(data => {
    this.typeDetails = data;
    console.log(this.typeDetails);
  });
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hence it is a `promise` you have to use `console.log(this.currentLocation);` inside the `resolve` method as shown below.Due to the `async` nature, you cannot log it outside the `promise`.B'cose you don't know which moment it'll have a value.

```
this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

      this.currentLocation ={
          lat :resp.coords.latitude,
          lng :resp.coords.longitude

      };

    console.log(this.currentLocation);//here you have to use log method

    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Error getting location', error);
    });
```